# how to print a cell range on cell edit in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a google sheet where people can come and scan a barcode and they will automatically get a receipt by cell range I will set

is there a way to print a receipt every time cell a1 is changing without someone should press control p or any other buttons?

Comment: Not unless the cell is edited by a user.  I find that printing on IOS is best done with the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google apps script can not trigger the print function, the only thing you can do is generate a PDF with the receipt and show the download/view URL in a dialog box.